# Qt Creator - auto code generation

Tags: application-development, qt-creator, html5

I have Ubuntu-Sdk IDE and I am doing HTML5 Programming in Qt Creator IDE, it is working absolutely fine, but when i click on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, Auto Code is not generating, Please let me know what can i do to get auto code in Qt Creator for HTML5, Any Plugin or anything is there ???

Answer (score 0):

There are no quick fixes defined for HTML5. Qt Creator is an IDE targeted at Qt development, so it fully supports C++/QML (and C, Obj-C and similar languages). HTML5 is out of scope for this IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Good question Amul

So as pointed out, HTML5 support is not currently within the scope (AFAIK) of the SDK. However, that is (Probably) only temporary as the SDK is in continuous development, where we now even see python being introduced.

- The first thing to do is register a launchpad account.
- The second thing to do is file a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu - Make sure this has not already been reported.
- Now if you truly wish to do something about this, I say fantastic. The SDK can use your help in defining this functionality. Come over to #ubuntu-app-devel in IRC and ask around as to how you can get started.

Now I did actually talk to a html5 developer friend on #ubuntu-app-devel and asked him what he does. He actually programs in sublime text, and builds in the Ubuntu SDK (qt creator)

So not a perfect answer, but I hope this helps at least a bit.